Is this Solution on Ordinal Arithmetic Correct (Cantor Normal Form)?
Question
Let $\beta=\omega + 3$. Calculate $\beta ^2,\beta ^3$ and $\beta ^4$ in Cantor Normal Form.
Attempt
Since $\beta = \omega + 3$, then $\beta ^2 = (\omega +3)(\omega +3) = (\omega +3).\omega + (\omega +3).3 = \omega ^2 + (\omega +3)+(\omega +3)+(\omega +3)=\omega + (3+\omega)+(3+\omega)+3 = \omega ^2 +\omega +\omega +\omega +3 = \omega ^2 +\omega .3+ 3.$
$\beta ^3 = \beta (\omega ^2+\omega .3+3)=\beta \omega ^2+\beta \omega .3 + \beta .\omega = (\omega +3)\omega ^2 + (\omega +3)\omega .3+(\omega +3)\omega = \omega ^3 +\omega ^2.3 +\omega ^2$.
I am not confident of my solution, and I keep getting ugly expressions for $\beta ^4$. I would appreciate it if you guys could be of help.

It is probably easier to just figure out what $\eta\cdot(\omega+3)$ is in general (for $\eta$ in CNF). This is not hard to do and much less confusing than a full expansion from scratch every time.

@TimSeifert If you don’t mind, could you give more details? I understand $\eta .(\omega +3)= \eta .\omega +\eta . 3$. Is this what you mean?

Well, of course, but the point would be to figure out the CNF of $\eta\cdot\omega$ in terms of the one for $\eta$ (and likewise for $\eta\cdot 3$). If you can manage that (which I'm sure you can), the calculation will simplify a lot.

This online ordinal number calculator will be useful to check your results. However, it only provides you with Cantor Normal Form results -- it doesn't display a sequence of calculations ("a sequence", because more than one way is usually possible) leading to the result.

Since ordinal addition and multiplication are not commutative, it is usually hard to write general formulas without invoking too many "if-cases" depending on the order of the different involved ordinals, so that specific rules somewhat need to be rederived for each computation.
In the present case, you calculated $\beta^2$ correctly, but not $\beta^3$. I would recommend you to go this way :
$$
\begin{align}
\beta^3 &= \beta^2 \cdot \beta & (a) \\
        &= (\omega^2 + \omega.3 + 3)(\omega + 3) \\
        &= (\omega^2 + \omega.3 + 3)\omega + (\omega^2 + \omega.3 + 3)3 & (b) \\
\end{align}
$$
where we used $(a)$ the definition of ordinal exponential and $(b)$ the distributivity of ordinal multiplication over ordinal addition. Then, the last term, namely $(\omega^2 + \omega.3 + 3)3$, can be handled as follows :
$$
\begin{align}
(\omega^2 + \omega.3 + 3)3 
   &= (\omega^2 + \omega.3 + 3) + (\omega^2 + \omega.3 + 3) + (\omega^2 + \omega.3 + 3) \\
   &= \omega^2 + (\omega.3 + 3 + \omega^2) + (\omega.3 + 3 + \omega^2) + \omega.3 + 3 & (c) \\
   &= \omega^2 + \omega^2 + \omega^2 + \omega.3 + 3 & (d) \\
   &= \omega^2.3 + \omega.3 + 3
\end{align}
$$
by $(c)$ associativity of the ordinal addition and $(d)$ the fact that transfinite ordinals absorbs smaller elements through addition, i.e. $\alpha + \beta = \displaystyle \sup_{n\in\beta} \alpha + n = \beta$ when $\alpha < \beta$ for non-finite $\beta$. In the same spirit, one finds :
$$
(\omega^2 + \omega.3 + 3)\omega
   = (\omega^2 + \omega.3 + 3) + \ldots + (\omega^2 + \omega.3 + 3)
   = \omega^3 + \omega.3 + 3,
$$
hence finally
$$
\beta^3 = (\omega^3 + \omega.3 + 3) + (\omega^2.3 + \omega.3 + 3) = \omega^3 + \omega^2.3 +  \omega.3 + 3
$$
You can try to generalize this procedure to the multiplication of ordinal numbers $\gamma = \omega^{\gamma_1}c_1 + \ldots + \omega^{\gamma_m}c_m$ and $\omega^{\delta_1}d_1 + \ldots + \omega^{\delta_n}c_n$ expressed in Cantor's normal form with $\gamma_1 \ge \delta_1$. One has
$$
\gamma \cdot \delta 
   = \left(\omega^{\gamma_1}c_1 + \ldots + \omega^{\gamma_m}c_m\right) \left(\omega^{\delta_1}d_1 + \ldots + \omega^{\delta_n}c_n\right) 
   = \sum_{k=1}^n \left(\omega^{\gamma_1}.c_1 + \ldots + \omega^{\gamma_m}c_m\right) \omega^{\delta_k}d_k 
$$
by left-distributivity, with
$$
\left(\omega^{\gamma_1}c_1 + \ldots + \omega^{\gamma_m}c_m\right) \omega^{\delta_k}d_k = \omega^{\gamma_1+\delta_k}d_k + \omega^{\gamma_2}c_2 + \ldots + \omega^{\gamma_m}c_m,
$$
where we used the relation $\omega^{\gamma_1}c_1 \cdot \omega^{\delta_k}d_k = \omega^{\gamma_1}(c_1\omega^{\delta_k})d_k = \omega^{\gamma_1+\delta_k}d_k$ by associativity of the multiplication. But deriving a general formula becomes a nightmare when recollecting all the terms inside the summation because the "middle terms", which may disappear or not depending on the order of the various exponents $\gamma_j \gtreqqless \gamma_l + \delta_k$. And the situation gets even more complicated when $\gamma_1 < \delta_1$. That is why doing sequences of small computations as you did is sometimes not the worst strategy.
After this digression, finally, you may find the fourth power of $\beta$ as $\beta^4 = \omega^4 + \omega^3.3 + \omega^2.3 + \omega.3 + 3$ and you will recognise the pattern being $\beta^n = \omega^n + \omega^{n-1}.3 + \ldots + \omega.3 + 3$.
